# TensorFlow: image preprocessing on GPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, multi-gpu

I have four GPU cards and CPU does not make image preprocessing fast enough for all of them. The queues are exhausted quickly and most of the time cards are idle. Is there a way to put QueueRunner on one of these four GPU cards so that one card does preprocessing and form the queue while three others actually train the model?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it should be possible. You can wrap the preprocessing python function in [tf.py_func](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/script_ops.html#py_func), creating a TF op and put it to the requested gpu using `with tf.device("gpu:0"):`, create a queue there and use the dequeue op on the other gpus.

Comment: Are you sure this works? I think the python function will still run on the CPU, right?

Comment: Please provide example code. Where exactly would you have to put the `with` around? I define image augmentation with `map()`s on Datasets.